# What can i make for this session please help me

Tags: php, session

i want to make a session for if the user clicked submit in login.php start a session and in profile.php if the session not started redirect user to login.php, so can you help me please

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please visit the [help] before posting.  StackOverflow is not a code-writing service; you must make an effort, show your work, and ask a _specific_ question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something on the lines of if I understand your question:

Login.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST)):
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
endif;
```

Profile.php

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])):
    header('Location: login.php');
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Elevant !